# $1 - x$ is a unit iff $x$ is nilpotent.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Suppose we have a $Z$ graded ring $R$ and $x \in R$ a homogeneous element of nonzero degree. Let $u = 1 - x.$ I want to show that $u$ is a unit iff $x$ is nilpotent. One direction is trivial. Now suppose $u$ is a unit. I am having trouble showing that $x$ is nilpotent.

I know that $u$ being a unit implies it is homogeneous. However, since $x = 1 - u$ and 1 is homogeneous of degree $0$ this must mean that $u$ must be homogeneous of degree $0$ as well as $x$ is homogeneous. But this implies that $x$ is homogeneous of degree 0 which is a contradiction. I feel as though I am missing something. Any hints would be appreciated!

Comment: The link and most links on that page only discuss the other direction. I'm not sure how to approach the direction that I am stuck with. I have tried to show that $1 - u$ is contained in every prime ideal but that doesn't seem to go anywhere either...

Comment: Is the other direction even true? See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2105778/if-1-x-is-a-ring-unit-then-is-this-ring-nilpotent).

Comment: "$u$ being unit implies it is homogeneous" -- that sounds definitely wrong. As a counterexample, in $\mathbb Z_{25}[X]$ we have $(1+5X)(1-5X)=1$, so $1+5X$ is a unit but definitely not homogenous.

Comment: Hmm you are correct. But I do think it is correct for graded domains...this does clear up some confusion though. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The key to the other direction was showing that if $x$ is nilpotent, then $1+x+\dots+x^{n-1}$ is the inverse of $1-x$. In this direction, you show that every possible inverse must look like this.

Let the degree of $x$ be $d$. Let $y$ be the inverse of $1-x$, and suppose that the $n^\text{th}$ component of $y$ in the grading is $c_n$. Then the $n^\text{th}$ component of $(1-x)y$ is $c_n-[x]c_{n-d}$ (where $[x]$ is the $d^\text{th}$ component of $x$). Since $(1-x)y=1$, this implies
$$
c_n-[x]c_{n-d}=\begin{cases}
  1 & n=0\\ 0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
In particular, if $m$ is the smallest index for which $c_m\neq 0$, then it must be true that $c_m=1$, and that $m=0$. You can also show that $c_i=0$ for all $m<i<m+d$. You then have
$$
c_{d}-c_0[x]=0\implies c_{d}=[x]
$$
and you can proceed by induction to show that $c_{kd}=[x]^k$. Since you cannot have infinitely many nonzero coordinates, some $[x]^k$ must equal zero.